# How do I make the rails file_field button bigger?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, forms, button

I can't seem to make the file_field button bigger in a rails form. Its size is alright when on a laptop or destop but isn't good on smaller screens. I'm using devise for registration and sessions and I've  set it up where you can edit the forms with custom css.

I tried adding a class name to it in the form and targeting the file_field with input {} but that hasn't changed its size.

```
<div class="profile-pic">
   <%= f.label "Add a profile pic" %><br />
   <%= f.file_field :avatar, class: "select_button" %>
</div><br />

.select_button {
   input {
      width: 400px;
      height: 300px;
   }
 }
```

[image]

I'm a hack at css so any insights would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try sizing the `.select_button` with `em` or `rem` instead of absolute pixels and see if that improves it. Something like `width: 2em; height: 1.2 em`.

Comment: Yeah I tried em and rem. Good suggestion though. Ugh, I wish I knew why it's not working. I swear I've made that file_field select button bigger before when doing a media query for max width of 500px...

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= f.file_field :avatar, class: "custom-file-input" %>
```

And in the CSS:

```
.custom-file-input::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.custom-file-input::before {
  content: 'Select some files';
  display: inline-block;
  background: linear-gradient(top, #f9f9f9, #e3e3e3);
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  outline: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 10pt;
}
.custom-file-input:hover::before {
  border-color: black;
}
.custom-file-input:active::before {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e3e3e3, #f9f9f9);
}
```

Refer: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/custom-file-input-styling-webkitblink/

Hope it should help you..

Comment: That would be alright if I was writing an html form however this is a rails app. So the form tags are different.

Comment: @dmberko11 It is exactly the same, Rails serves HTML to the browser, so you have all the styling possibilities, just do `<%= f.file_field :avatar, class: "custom-file-input" %>`

Comment: @RolandStuder thanks for your answer and you're right about the html. It's still not working though. I tried a similar approach to what you had before. Sorry for the super delayed response. I only program as a hobby at this time in life.

Comment: I think I can get it to work. I was using Atom as my IDE and that was causing so many issues. It didn’t compile my JavaScript correctly at all. I would console.log stuff and get ridiculous unforced errors. Switched to sublime and problem solved. I have a feeling my stylesheet conundrum with the silly file_field select input will be resolved too with sublime lol. Oy ve